# How to get objects in a list stored in a hasmap, to create new list

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

So I have a hashmap which stores strings as the key and lists as the value.

I need to create a new list inside my method, populate my new list with the one stored inside the hashmap.

Doing this I am not sure how to get all the objects of the list in the hashmap into the new list...

```
//Original hashmap
private Map<String, List<Object>> things;

//inside the method im trying to create...
List<Object> otherThings = new ArrayList<>();

//unsure what i need here:
otherThings.add....
```

The new List should have all the objects from the list stored in the hashmap.

Comment: No, you don't need to create a new list and to store the object in that new list just to call a method on that object. All you need is a reference to the object. So, for example: `things.get("someKey").get(someIndex).increment()`.

Comment: specifically tells me in the question me that i need to create a list and populate it with the list found in the hashmap.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly. Your question says that you belive that you need to create a new list in order to increment an object from a list of the map. My comment justs says that no, in order to increment the property of an object, you don't need to create a new list. If you *want* to create a new list, then create a new list, but that has nothing to do with inrementing a property of an object. You should clarify what you want to achieve. Providing an example input and an example output would help.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

```
private Map<String, List<Object>> things;
List<Object> otherThings = new ArrayList<>();
otherThings.addAll(things.get("some_key"));
```

This retrieves the list that matches "some_key" in the hashmap and copies the contents into a new list for otherThings.  Keep in mind that only the list is copied, but the object references are still the same.

Comment: Or just simply `List<Object> otherThings = new ArrayList<>(things.get("some_key"));`

Comment: Thanks, guys, couldn't seem to get the addAll method to work... not sure why, but I basically iterated through the list and added them each individually with a for loop.